# Find all critical points of the function $f(x,y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)$ and determine which are min, max and saddle points.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm quite confused how to determine which are min, max and saddle points because if I do the partial derivatives I I get pairs of $\pi/2+k\pi$ and $k\pi$, which means that I have an infinite number of points.

How do I find the pattern? I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please show us a little more of your work. Hint: why shouldn't there be infinitely many points to think about   What if you were asked the corresponding question just about the function $\cos$? Please use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: do you mean cos(xy)? I am a bit confused by the hint. Yes, cos is periodic but that means that f(x y) for the pairs of critical points will have the same 3 values 0, 1, and -1 right?

Comment: The single variable function $\cos x$ has infinitely many local maxima and minima. The maximum value is $1$; it occurs infinitely often. Your function of two variables also has infinitely many  critical points. Your job is to find them. You could start by drawing a graph, by hand or in Excel or any of a number of online graphing apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The critical points are those where both partial derivatives vanish:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-\sin x\cos y
\qquad
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=-\cos x\sin y
$$
There are indeed infinitely many points where both derivatives vanish:

1. $\sin x=0$ and $\sin y=0$, or
2. $\cos y=0$ and $\cos x=0$,

using the fact that $\cos\alpha\ne0$ if $\sin\alpha\ne0$ and conversely.

The first solution set corresponds to $x=h\pi$ and $y=k\pi$, the second solution set corresponds to $x=\pi/2+l\pi$ and $y=\pi/2+m\pi$.

Note that $h,k,l,m$ can be *any* integer.

Now we can look at the Hessian:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}&=-\cos x\cos y\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\,\partial y}&=-\sin x\sin y\\
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}&=-\cos x\cos y
\end{align}
so we get
$$
H(x,y)=\det\begin{bmatrix}
-\cos x\cos y & -\sin x\sin y \\
-\sin x\sin y & -\cos x\cos y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\cos^2x\cos^2y-\sin^2x\sin^2y
$$
What can you say about $H(h\pi,k\pi)$ and about $H(\pi/2+l\pi,\pi/2+m\pi)$?

Comment: they will be 1, respectively -1